# FlowType errors using Object.entries

Tags: flowtype

So, I have the following code, but flow errors keep popping up. I've tried to cast the Object.entries, but just won't work - others things to. Any insight?

```
type Fields = {
  name: string,
  func: (*) => boolean
};

type S = {
  key1: Fields,
  bill: Fields
}

var a: S = {
  key1: {name: 'mary', func: (str) => str === 'mary'},
  bill: {name: 'bill', func: (str) => str === 'bill'}
}

var c = Object
  .entries(a)
  .map(([key, obj]) => obj.func(key) ? obj : false)
  .filter(f => f)
  .reduce((acc, c) => {
    return 'something here'
   }, {});
```

I've left some things off, but the slow is the same. Flow is reading that entries as a return Tuple Type. I've tried all sorts of things, but instead of mudding things up, I left it untouched.

I can't seem to annotate the destructured items here ([key, obj]), get tuple errors...

Any assistance on getting that code assigned to var c, to work with annotations etc..?

The errors I get:
  Cannot call method on mixed type (from obj.func)
  Cannot assign value in Tuple etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is accurate. [`Object.entries` has the type](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/77c6bed34878a7904e97050ac6991dd7c9f80f17/lib/core.js#L38)

> entries(object: any): Array<[string, mixed]>;

It has no way to know what the type of the second item in the tuple will be. That means your code

```
.map(([key, obj]) => obj.func(key) ? obj : false)
```

would need to do

```
.map(([key, obj]) => {
    if (typeof obj.func !== 'function') throw new Error();
    return obj.func(key) ? obj : false;
})
```

so that flow knows that it is guaranteed to be a function.

Alternatively, you could change your data structure to use a type where the second item in the tuple has a guaranteed type, like `Map`, e.g.

```
type Fields = {
  name: string,
  func: (string) => boolean
};

type S = Map<string, Fields>;

var a: S = new Map([
  ['key1', {name: 'mary', func: (str) => str === 'mary'}],
  ['bill', {name: 'bill', func: (str) => str === 'bill'}],
]);

var c = Array.from(a, ([key, obj]) => obj.func(key) ? obj : false)
  .filter(f => f)
  .reduce((acc, c) => {
    return 'something here'
   }, {});
```

Comment: as a side note, how would you annotate the obj in [key, obj], i'm using [key, obj]:[string, *], but feels dirty.

Comment: Also, I was hoping you could cast the Array<[string, mixed]> into something else.

Comment: Items with the `mixed` type will accept any type as input, but you need to use Flow's [type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) to prove what type it is before you use it, which is what my `typeof obj.func !== 'function'` snippet is doing. You can't cast a mixed type to anything else because it could be anything and Flow's whole job is to prevent using the wrong types in places. `any` is the only type you can convert to _and_ from, so casting to `any` would be the only option, and then you might as well not use Flow.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had:

```
    let objectsByName : { [string] : MyObjectType } = {}; //simple map
    ...
    objectsByName[object.name] = object; //call repeatedly to populate map.
    ...
    let results : any[] = []; //next we will populate this
```

Trying to operate on it like this failed for Flow (though this is executable JavaScript):

```
    for (let [name : string, object : MyObjectType] of Object.entries(objectsByName))
    {
        let result = doSomethingWith(object); //<- error on arg
        results.push(result);
    }
```

This succeeded for Flow:

```
    for (let name : string in objectsByName)
    {
        let object = objectsByName[name];
        let result = doSomethingWith(object); //<- error on arg
        results.push(result);
    }
```

It is annoying having to change code structure to suit a supposedly non-intrusive system like Flow [comment types](https://flow.org/blog/2015/02/20/Flow-Comments/), which I chose in the hopes of making my code completely oblivious to Flow's presence. In this case I have to make an exception and structure my code as *Flow* wants it.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing Object.entries with Object.keys + lookup fixes flow errors for me assuming the input object is properly typed.

i.e. replace `Object.entries(a)` with  `Object.keys(a).map(key => [key, a[key]])`

This works with flow:

```
type Fields = {
  name: string,
  func: (*) => boolean
};

type S = {
  key1: Fields,
  bill: Fields
}

var a: S = {
  key1: {name: 'mary', func: (str) => str === 'mary'},
  bill: {name: 'bill', func: (str) => str === 'bill'}
}

var c = Object
  .keys(a)
  .map(key => a[key].func(key) ? obj : false)
  .filter(f => f)
  .reduce((acc, c) => {
    return 'something here'
   }, {});
```